# Axios catches "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" inside of Reactjs frontend but same call works in nodejs, why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I use function below in the useEffect function of a ReactJs App. On the first request to /login axios already is catching this error

> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**But if I run this function in a nodejs app it works.** Why is that? It uses HTTP because there is now ssl cert installed yet. This is going to be a chrome extension for my companys internal usage only. Atm I dunno how to use a backend nodejs server in a chrome extension... maybe that would help? I also tried the request with fetch but no success, same results/err.

```
const getSwitchFlows = async () => {
  const dataString =
    'username=myurlencodedusername&password=myurlencodedpassword';
  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://myfully.qualifieddomainname.com:PORT/login',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    data: dataString,
  };
  const res = await axios(config);
  if (typeof res.data !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof res.data.token !== 'undefined') {
      const config2 = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://myfully.qualifieddomainname.com:PORT/api/v1/flows?ids=405',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${res.data.token}`,
        },
      };
      const res2 = await axios(config2);
      if (typeof res2.data !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(res2.data);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

[image: Chrome Network Tab]

[image: Chrome console]

Comment: do you get an CORS error?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the error object. No, no CORS error. There is also no response object... So now response.statusText...

Comment: try adding `"access-control-allow-origin": "http://you_domain_or_localhost:4000/"` to the headers in the `config` object of axios. (replace the port with the one you use obviously :) )

Comment: @liminor you most certainly do **not** add `access-control-allow-origin` to any request header. That is a response header that must come from the server

Comment: @SuperSpamTube what does your dev-tools _Network_ panel show? Is there any more detail?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the Network Tab as well

Comment: @liminor I tested this. Adding this header to my request did not change anything.
I am also of the opinion that this header is returned by the server and must therefore also be set there. In addition, as I said, the request works if I run it from a nodejs script.

Comment: Do you happen to be running an ad blocker? Try disabling extensions or even try a different browser